# What are variables life time running Python on Google Cloud?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

When I run a Python program on a `Google Function`, I would like to read some array from DB every day *once*, and make sure it is always available to use on the next `http requests`.

Currently an `array` is hardcoded:

```
array = [a,b,c,d]
```

I would like to read it everyday once, and **not** and on each `http request` to make it faster:

```
 array = read daily from server
```

Question is - say I read it today, do I have a **guarantee** that this variable will be available to all the next 1000 `http` requests? basically forever? what is it's life time ?
Do python program on a server **restart/built again for every request** like on my computer?

Comment: The whole point is that it's not running when it's not active. So no, you can't do that. If you have a DB already they why not read from it when you need to?

Comment: thanks, as I said, things needs to be super fast, and this array is an index being used by UI so can't be read every request. Can I just write it to a local file using python 'open' ?

Comment: also if this index is large, does its makes the program start slower on http request because it has to load a larger program? trying to compare that to reading it every request.

Comment: Cloud Functions don't preserve the state between invocations. No chance to keep any information reliably, unless the state is stored somewhere else. Somewhere else can be with a better latency than a database, but still you are to get the data using some API every time the cloud function is invoked or every time it is initialized.

Comment: thanks, why "using some API" ? I can get the data from a local dictionary which will be downloaded and hard written into a file, which is x2 faster than DB. Am I wrong?

Comment: where that 'file' is going to be reliably stored between invocations? Cloud functions don't have any 'hard drives'... only memory. And when the container (where the cloud function is executed) is 'terminated' all memory is erased. You can create a 'global' python variable and initialize it with some data (i.e from a database), but you don't have control when such initialization happens.

Comment: that file is a normal .py file with a dictionary hard written into it, so it is like part of the program, a normal file you can open, and inside you see dic={}  :). I do this localy and it works, even though on my Mac the program is being built every run, this file is being written once with the Python open file API. ( not sure you understand, I mean actually writing dic into a file, not copying a reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After writing a dozen comments to different answers on this question, I decided to consolidate my opinion in one answer.

**Disclaimer**: Unfortunately I don't work and I've never worked for Google, so the text below - is based on reading documentation, whitepapers, blogs, and personal experience. I might be wrong!!!

**Disclaimer**: I tried to simplify and omitted a lot of details. The real implementation and behavior - much more complex.

**Disclaimer**: I don't know the particular context, scope and requirements of the original question. Thus, I have to apply plenty of assumptions.

The answer consists of 3 parts - a general description of cloud functions state machine; description of a few frequent scenarios; and some comments and advises - related to the original question.

## Cloud Functions state machine

See the diagram with the description below it.

[image: State Machine Diagram]

I would suggest to consider 3 states - the first state is a 'global' (or shared between many run-time containers/environments); the other two - are per runtime container/environment - not an ideal description, but anyway:

### DEPLOYED (COLD)

- this is the first state - the source code with various parameters is deployed into the GCP project. The source code is parsed, but there is no run-time container, where the cloud function (instance) is waiting for invocation. From this state - the cloud function can be initialized, or completely deleted.

### INITIALIZED (HOT)

- the run time environment for a cloud function is prepared in a container. One time initialization is done. The source code is loaded into the memory. The function is ready (hot) for invocation. If the initialization includes fetching some external data - that data is copied into the cloud function instance memory, thus if the original data source is modified later, the cloud function instance copy has the stale version of that data. Bear in mind that there may be (nearly) arbitrary number of initialized containers for a given cloud function (source code). That number is controlled by the Cloud Functions service (by Google), rather than by the client. In my experience the cloud function can stay in this state without 'movements' for quite a while - maybe up to half an hour. From this state the cloud function can be invoked, or released (killed).

### RUNNING

- the cloud function instance is invoked after binding a request to a container with the initialized cloud function. The cloud function instance can stay in this state until the execution is finished, a timeout or run-time crash happens. From this state the cloud function can finish and return to the INITIALIZED (HOT) state, or can crash completely ( I understand that the whole container is killed in this case).

There may be a few state transitions:

`1 - deploy` - the first possible state transition happens during the cloud function deployment process (i.e. source code, configuration and environment parsing and checking). This state transition leads to the DEPLOYED (COLD) state.

`2 - initialize` - happens when the Cloud Function service (Google) decides that a new container is to be initialized with the chosen cloud function. Initialization always happens from the latest available source code (which is loaded into the container memory and is available there). During this process a 'global' (outside of the cloud function entry point function) code is executed - for example an `init` function in case of Go language; as well as initialization of various global variables. This state transition leads to the INITIALIZED (HOT) state.

`3 - invoke` - happens when the Cloud Function service (Google) binds the incoming request with the available (free) initialized (hot) cloud function instance and calls the entry point function. This state transition leads to the RUNNING state.

`4 - finish` - happens when the cloud function finishes its execution. This state transition leads to the INITIALIZED (HOT) state.

`5 - crash` - happens when something goes completely wrong inside the cloud function code. I do understand that the whole container is killed in such case. This state transition leads to the DEPLOYED (COLD) state.

`6 - release (kill)` - happens when the Cloud Function service (Google) decides to release memory from the runtime container/environment. This state transition leads to the DEPLOYED (COLD) state.

`7 - delete` -  happens when the client deletes the cloud function completely.

## A few scenarios - very simplified description

### Deployment of a cloud function.

I understand - up to 3 state transitions happen - `1 - deploy`; `2 - initialize`; and optional `6 - release (kill)` if there is no immediate invocation of a cloud function instance. Bear in mind that the deployment process does not affect cloud functions, which are already in a runtime container -  INITIALIZED (HOT) and RUNNING states. And they can continue being up and down in those states ('invocation' and 'finish' state transitions) for a while - minutes, hours. However, the next initialization (of a runtime container - 'initialism' state transition) happens from the most recent version of the deployed source code. Bear in mind - the replacement of old code with the new code in the 'hot' containers - takes time - minutes, and maybe hours.

### Invocation of a cloud function.

Cloud Function service (Google) checks if there is a container with the INITIALIZED (HOT) cloud function. If such cloud function instance exists - invoke it. Otherwise check the maximum number of possible cloud function instances. If the threshold is not archived - 'initialize' a cloud function from the latest available DEPLOYED (COLD) state (the most recent deployed code), and invoke it upon initialization.

### Termination of a cloud function container.

Cloud Function service (Google) checks if there is a container with the INITIALIZED (HOT) cloud function, which has not been invoked for some time (from a few seconds/minutes maybe up to half an hour). And kills it, releasing all memory. If that container cloud function instance has anything in its pseudo directory `temp` - all of that is gone as well.

## A few comments about the original question

- Cloud Functions are stateless. And should be idempotent. Their behavior is completely dependent on the external data (either it comes with the request, or the data is fetched during the request handling).
- Feel free to use a pseudo file system (`tmp`directory), but don't expect anything there (and don't use any data you find there) when the cloud function instance is invoked. Best practice - delete everything from there before finishing the cloud function instance invocation execution.
- Feel free to pack anything with the source code and use it at run time. But be prepared - that data is of the same age as your running code. The recently deployed code (and it's auxiliary data) can be a few versions ahead than the code which is being executed.
- The less initialization you have - the faster the `2 - initialize` state transition is done, and the faster your cloud function comes to the INITIALIZED (HOT) state. Only immutable things are worth to initialize - global constants, some API clients. There is no material difference between an ordinary initialization, and a "lazy" initialization (there might be in some very specific corner cases).
- Configuration and cache - are to be external, outside of the cloud function. You have to get the data from them on every invocation. And maybe update them as well. All of that - is like a state of the process - should be outside of the cloud function.
- Using external API is inevitable. If some cache is required and the latency is critical - use Go instead of Python, find some storage with minimum latency (i.e. Firestore might be a good candidate), and keep the persistent data there.

One cloud function (or one functional component) - one service account. With minimum IAM roles and permissions.

And so on…

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a Cloud Functions instance as a server. When you start it, you can load the global variable that you want and you keep that data in memory. As long as your server is up and running, the data in global scope are kept. If you start a new server, you have to reload that global variables because it's a new environment.

The Cloud Funcitons instances work exactly in the same way. 1 request can be only processed by 1 instance at a time (for v1). I mean, if you have 2 concurrent requests, 2 instances are created and each request is processed on their dedicated instances.

Because you have many parallel instances, you could load many time your data from the source. In addition, the Cloud Functions are offloaded after a time without any request processing (between 10 and 30 minutes). And it can scale to 0.

At the opposite, if you have sustained traffic on Cloud Functions you can keep the same instance up and running during hours and days. There is no expiration and you have to manage yourself the cache invalidation.

Lastly, because you load stuff in the global scope, at startup, you will slow the cold start, I mean the duration that your Cloud Functions take to start and to serve the request.

Comment: thank you, what if my function will access DB, download the dic, then use Open File API, hard code it into a normal py file, then it stay there forever. Is this file write something that happens per instance? I mean if I do write to a file (with open() as) would it save my new file forever? I do this locally and it works great, I actually write data from db to source code and it stay between builds.

Comment: Unfortunately, it won’t. It could be saved into the `tmp` directory until the container with the initialised cloud function is “killed”. And, as a user of the Cloud Function service, you don’t have direct control over it.

Comment: Exact, you load the container, and the file system in memory. The container is immutable, and the memory ephemeral. Therefore, you can't save the file inside Cloud Functions. But you can save it externally, in Cloud Storage, and then load it when a new function starts.

Comment: Personally, I probably would use Firestore as a cache (on every invocation), but you may choose other sources (i.e. Cloud Storage is a good one), and take a risk using global variables on initialization...

Comment: wow so I can't store any data between invocations ? that makes the system less faster because there is so much data one wants to keep, instead of accessing a DB every run, especially if this data changes once a week or so.

Comment: What do you mean by invocation? If you mean invocation on the same instance, yes, you can keep data in memory (or in the in memory file system). But you can't keep data between 2 instances: when the instances is gone, all the data in memory (or in the in memory file system) disappear. It's the standard behavior of Google Cloud Serverless product. However, I recommend you to have a look to Cloud Run 2 gen environment runtime: still in preview but you can mount network file system on the instances (GCSFuse or Filestore).

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere not sure what 'same instance' mean, and how do ii know it's the same, I just need my program to ask data from server every 4th day, and HARD CODE a dictionary into an EXISTING py file, by hard code I mean turn it into a source code you can see the keys/values in your eyes (File Open API), why would this change? and how can I make sure there is "1 instance" when I do that ?

Comment: Why don't you do that in a CI/CD pipeline before deploying the functions?

Comment: When you make a connection to "an instance" this happens: If one does not already exist that is capable of serving the request, then one is created. It's quite possible that each and every request you make _goes to a different instance_ every single time.

Comment: the instance copy all the program file every time ? or use the original files? because it sounds not reasonable it copy all my source code the moment I send a request. If it doesn't, then as I said, my original source code will be edited, and reflect to all instances.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want:

```
data = None

def get_data():
    global data
    if not data:
        data = get_data_from_somewhere_slow()
        return data
```

Between invocations it's possible that the instance remains active and will then serve the next request with a "hot" cache where the global data remains populated. It's not strictly true that it's one request per instance, it's just true sufficiently such that it's not worth making much effort to persist data across invocations.

You can read then cache the data from a local file like this (or indeed a DB), so the "slow" place you are getting data from is your local file (or the DB). But then you might as well just put it directly in the source code itself and "read" it from there when you need it.

You also then have the issue that you cannot update that local file without doing a deployment (hence DB's) , as you'll need to update the data directly.

So if you are happy to do a deployment to update the data you can read superfast from a local file without a database call.

However consider that every site in the world, almost, is wired up to a DB and performance can be super fast. So how fast does fast need to be, exactly?

What problem are you trying to solve? Reading some value once (why?) or serving above some speed limit? Decide that and you'll get a better answer.

Comment: In the proposed approach, one does not have control over the `cache' invalidation. It might be very risky, and lead to cases when the cloud function uses stale data. Or there should be some time based mechanism for the cache reloading (not ideal as well, as it may require frequent reloading of not yet modified data, and still cases with out of date data). Another approach - keep the data hard coded in the source code - does not solve the issue either - redeployment of a cloud function does not immediately lead to re-initialization of it in the container.

Comment: I have an index I need to use RIGHT when the user send http request, and I need it every time, it is a 1000 keys dic, so instead of read it every time, I have it locally. But, sometimes it's being updated on server and I want to get updates each x days. What about getting it from db sometimes, writing to a file (changing actual source code ) with the python Open File API ? I do this on my Mac and it works, so every x days I download data from db, write it to source code(Open File), then its is available forever. Is this something that works also on the server?

Comment: It won’t unfortunately. You cannot reliably store any data in the cloud function run time environment between invocations. 
You can play and take some risk, but it can lead to errors, which are very, very difficult to find and resolved.

Comment: I don't store data, I write into file, like hard-coded, if I can write into file on my Mac then turn off the Mac and turn it on, and the file is there like any source code, what's the different on a server? that it's a different instance ?

Comment: The difference is you can add files to your Mac and there is one of them. In the cloud there might be dozens of "servers" and some may have stale data. A database will always be a single source of truth.

Comment: You can't write to local files on these sorts of services. Stop trying to make it work your way and learn the way it was designed to work.

Comment: A 'server' (or a 'container'), you probably have in mind, does not have any persistent storage (i.e. hard drive as your laptop has). It has only RAM. And as soon as the 'power' is switched off - all data is lost.

Comment: You can modify your source code (and hard code new values), and redeploy a cloud function. But that won't solve your issue either. Because it takes time (maybe many minutes) to initialize all running instances of your cloud function from the new source code. In that situation some of your cloud functions invocations use old code, and some - new code. Gradually all old 'containers' (with old code) are killed, and only new code becomes in use...

Comment: @PaulCollingwood not sure what "you can't" means, but it IS WORKING NOW on the server exactly as I described, already for a day.

Comment: @al-dann , i am really surprised by your comments, because it does work on the server ( I know, you will say that its not stable, but it works for a while now). This is not a STORAGE, this is a py file that already exist, and I write into it, like hardcode dic into it. I think writing to a file, and make it part of the hardcode, works, and no need to reinitiate all values because this dic is being used only at the moment of http request, it's not that the whole code depend on it, it is just an index.

Comment: Great! I'm glad. You'll make a mistake deploying the update one day however and you'll move to a more robust system. But if it works, for you, great.

Comment: When I say you can't write to local files what I mean exactly is that you "can't rely on it". It might work, and work for a long time but one day you'll have two servers running with two different versions of the data and no way to tell which is which. Hence the DB as a source of truth.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is to hardcode this 1000 key dict right into your source code.

Another approach would be to create a daily build process that

1. Reads your dict from the DB and writes it directly into your python source file (or a nearby file that your script reads at startup)
2. Packages up the python source and deploys it replace the current  cloud function

Now your Cloud Function doesn't have to worry about connecting to DB's or invalidating caches.

If it turns out you need to update more often, change the build from daily to every 12 hours or whatever timing is best.
Josh

Comment: I would suggest to think about the proposed solution as about very risky. Because the 'replacement' (of old functions with updated functions) can take some time, during which your cloud function behavior may be a bit random (between the 'old' and the 'new' values) .

Comment: that is exactly what I do, and people here said it won't work... @al-dann, not sure what you mean "take some time" but I can set the timeout to be 540 seconds, I currently use the function to aggregate data and it takes 60 seconds and works great. To download and hardcode a dic into the source code, takes around 1 seconds, and I still do not understand why this is not safe.